# How do you redirect to a specific page after login in blazor, using AspNetCore Identity?

Tags: blazor, asp.net-identity

I created a new Blazor project using the new .Net 8 Blazor Web App, and included Automatic Render mode and Individual Account authentication.  All the bells and whistles.

I'm writing a site where it's split down the center between half marketing and half end user portal.

I started by breaking things and creating a new Layout for the marketing side.  It's a simple div with "Hello World" and a link to login.

The new Blazor scaffolded templates for login are pretty nice.  After Login, the end user returns back to the root of the site.

I want the user to return to the "dashboard", so I went looking for configurations I could make to tell the application to go to the dashboard.  I found things like writing a component and putting it in the AuthorizeView component. I found articles claiming that you had to set the returnurl in the appsettings.json file. I found others that said you had to specify the return url in the program.cs when configuring authentication.

None of this worked.  I almost got the AuthorizeView one working, but it felt like it was overkill.  There HAS to be a simple way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that the most simple way is to include the return url in the link to your login page...

```
<a href="/account/login?ReturnUrl=%2FDashboard">Login</a>
```

And, like that.... magic. Replace Dashboard with relative path to wherever you want a person to go after login.